# Running apache + mod_wsgi as different user

Tags: apache-2.2, python, mod-wsgi, users, uid

I have a django project, which I am moving from the dev-server to apache. I have managed to get it server with mod_wsgi, but it runs as apache. Mod_wsgi documentation says, that if apache is run as root, it is possible to run mod_wsgi process as a different user.

Q1: Is it possible to run mod_wsgi as different user without running apache as root?

Q2: If answer to the above is no, how do I make apache run as root. I am using the provided repository provided httpd package on a CentOS 6 machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache every time start as root on RHEL derivates (like CentOS).
Then it uses setuid to switch to user/group configured in httpd.conf.

From mod_wsgi [docs](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess):

> Note that having denoted that daemon processes should be created by
>   using the WSGIDaemonProcess directive, the WSGIProcessGroup directive
>   still needs to be used to delegate specific WSGI applications to
>   execute within those daemon processes.
>
> Also note that the name of the daemon process group must be unique for
>   the whole server. That is, it is not possible to use the same daemon
>   process group name in different virtual hosts.
>
> Options which can be supplied to the WSGIDaemonProcess directive are:
>
> **user=name | user=#uid**